# `boost::simd::bitwise_and` and type compatibility

Tags: c++, boost, simd, avx

I use `boost::simd` for my program. Curiously, the whole program runs in fact slower with the use of `boost::simd` compared to without. I managed to track down the line that causes the overwhelming majority of CPU runtime:

```
using pack_t = boost::simd::pack<double>;
using logical_pack_t = boost::simd::pack<boost::simd::logical<double>, pack_t::static_size>;
using iters_pack_t = boost::simd::pack<std::uint64_t, pack_t::static_size>;
static_assert(sizeof(double) == sizeof(std::uint64_t), "mismatch of pack sizes");

const iters_pack_t zero(0);
const iters_pack_t one(1);

iters_pack_t increment(1);

logical_pack_t condition = /* ... */;

increment = boost::simd::if_else(condition, one, zero); // bottleneck
increment = boost::simd::bitwise_and(increment, condition); // better version, doesn't compile
```

As stated in the source code, I assume that `bitwise_and` should bring a performance boost. However, when trying to compile that variant, my compiler prints pages of cryptic error messages (as always with TMP-based libraries). I suppose that this is due to the fact that `increment` and `condition` are not of the same type. This assumption is supported by the fact that the code compiles once I change that line to the nonsensical `increment = boost::simd::bitwise_and(increment, increment);`.

[The documentation](http://numscale.github.io/boost.simd/group__group-bitwise_gaa3e9185f5e6b7e61e2f634aaea5a450f.html) states that both operands must solely share the same bit size, which they do in my case. Therefore, I don't understand why my code doesn't compile.

Compiled with `-march=native` on an Ivy Bridge (AVX support but not AVX2).

Comment: In the final ASM, to increment a vector of counters based on a comparison, the most efficient way is to take advantage of the fact that PCMPEQ compare-masks of all-zero and all-one also work as 0 or -1.  With Intel intrinsics, this looks like `count = _mm_sub_epi32(count, _mm_cmp_epi32(a, b));`.  This is significantly better than masking a vector of `1`s and adding that.

Comment: This exact optimization is wrapped by  boost::simd::if_inc

Comment: @JoelFalcou I've successfully solved my problem with the aid of boost::simd::if_inc. This increased the speedup factor between canonical and SIMD to 3.7.

Comment: Great to hear. I will however check why your other code is giving you a bad time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things :

- are you using the old boost.SIMD living in NT2 or the new autonomous version at https://github.com/NumScale/boost.simd ? The latest should have better performances.
- The best course of action is to use [boost::simd::if_inc](http://developer.numscale.com/boost.simd/current/group__group-boolean_gadf9a61fa57013e658ad4125ca4559f8d.html#gadf9a61fa57013e658ad4125ca4559f8d) that do the correct optimization whenever its possible by using the bitwise representation of True (aka -1) to do the computation.

Comment: Yes, I am indeed using the code fetched from the independent repository. And your proposed solution doesn't seem to work for me, unfortunately. [This code](http://pastebin.com/CVYD3ihB) prints about 500 lines of error messages, nested up to 30 files deep.

Comment: could you give me the exact command line you're using at the moment and the SHA1 of the version of Bosot.SIMD you're using (or the tag if any) ?

Comment: Command line: `clang++ --target=x86_64-w64-mingw32 -Wall -Wextra -std=c++14 -O3 -march=native -DNDEBUG test.cxx -o test.exe -I"C:\Dev\boost\include" -I"C:\Dev\boost.simd\include"`

Comment: The version with which the error occurs is a develop branch snapshot from 05.11.2016.

SHA1 checksum for data: FE772DEA0C82E48D7A3E7E8C343EB166E8800CBE
SHA1 checksum for data and names: 1F5EAD64FE4EE593FF661695532266DB66723371

PS: it's a Clang 3.9.0 on a mingw32-w64 with GCC 6.2.0

Comment: Issue reproduced. Will get that fixed.